# increasing entry number automatically for every insert on a specific table

Tags: postgresql

i used this code and created a trigger function afterwards. it works fine if there is already a value in the entry number(eno) field but doesn't if the field is null

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION eno_inc() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $eno_inc$
DECLARE
enmb INTEGER; 
BEGIN
select max(eno) into enmb from entry;
new.eno := enmb + 1;
return new;
END;
$eno_inc$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

how do I solve this problem??
P.S I can't use 'serial' or 'sequence' because the course organiser wants a trigger for that function

Comment: I think you've left out something important here, as your comments to the various answers don't seem to add up properly. Can you expand on the question?

Answer (score 1):

So what you want is specialized behavior that only fires in the specific **case when** the field **is null**.

Phrased that way, you've basically answered your own question:

```
  CASE WHEN enmb IS NULL THEN new.eno := 1;
  ELSE new.eno := enmb + 1;
  END CASE
```

Comment: I don't use postgresql myself; I think I found the problem though. Adjusting.

Comment: still giving syntax errors **syntax error at or near "ELSE"**

Comment: I don't have a way to test it, so I can't say for certain what the issue is. Have a look at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/functions-conditional.html

Comment: @MahonixHonix What was the fix? I'll edit it into the answer so it can help future people with similar problems

Comment: I think `IF enmb IS NULL THEN new.eno := 1; ELSE new.eno := enmb + 1; END IF;` or `CASE WHEN enmb IS NULL THEN new.eno := 1; ELSE new.eno := enmb + 1; END CASE;` are what you're looking for here.

Comment: @muistooshort AHA, thanks! That's the sort of syntax issue I figured I'd made by not being familiar with this flavor of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Use [COALESCE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) (which is standard SQL):

> The `COALESCE` function returns the first of its arguments that is not null. Null is returned only if all arguments are null.

So something like this should give you a zero in `enmb` when `entry` is empty instead of your current NULL:

```
select coalesce(max(eno), 0) into enmb from entry;
```

Comment: still generates error message **null value in column "eno" violates not-null constraint**

Comment: @MahonixHonix That sounds like a problem with your databse. Was "eno" declared as NOT NULL in the first place?

Comment: @Mahonix: Works fine for me (yes, I even tried it). What exactly are you doing? Are you using that SELECT in your trigger function? Have you attached the trigger to the table with `create trigger ... before insert on entry ...`?

Comment: @Yamikuronue 'eno' is the primary key for the table so it can't be null

Comment: @MahonixHonix "But it doesn't [work] if the field is null" was throwing me off. It's not the field being null that's the problem, it's the table being empty; you might want to edit that into the question.

Comment: @Yamikuronue: But if the table is empty then `coalesce(max(eno), 0)` should result in a zero so I'm wondering what Mahonix is really doing, something is going on that we're not being told about.